# Android Manifest Inner classes should use $ rather than

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I m getting this warning in manifest `Inner classes should use $ rather than.` So i changed

```
<activity
            android:name=".User_Functionality.Display_Screen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Into

```
<activity
            android:name=".User_Functionality$Display_Screen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

but after changing into `$` i m getting error `Unresolved class User_Functionality` and i also tried to make `User_Functionality` into lower case but still getting error in manifest file.

Comment: why would you want to create inner activity class?

Comment: Well, is `.User_Functionality.Display_Screen` an inner class? How does its package name relate to your manifest package name?

Comment: Your [mcve] should include the implementation of `User_Functionality` and `Display_Screen`.

Comment: @ConfusedPup creating activity is requirement of app.

Comment: ofc it is but thing I dont understand is why as inner class?

Comment: @laalto .User_Functionality is package name which has  Display_Screen activity.

Comment: Package names ought to be in lowercase. That's what confuses the tooling to think it's an inner class.

Comment: @laalto you right but i also tried with lower case as i mentioned in question too

Comment: @ConfusedPup please check above comment.User_Functionality is package name not class.